# checking if download link works in python

Tags: python

Im currently using the following code to download gz file.  The url of the gz file will be constructed from pieces of information provided by the user:

```
generalUrl = theWebsiteURL + "/" + packageName
```

So generalURl can contain something like: `http://www.example.com/blah-0.1.0.tar.gz`

```
        res = requests.get(generalUrl)
        res.raise_for_status()
```

The problem I have here is; I have a list of websites for the variable called `theWebsiteURL`.  I need to check all of these websites to see which ones have the package in `packageName` available for download.  I would prefer not to download the package during the confirmation.

Once the code goes through the list of websites to discover which ones have the  package, I then want to pick the first website from the list of websites that were found to have the package and automatically download the package from it.

something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2.7
listOfWebsites = [ website1, website2, website3, website4, and so on ]
goodWebsites = []
for eachWebsite in listOfWebsites:
        genURL = eachWebsite + "/" + packageName
        res = requests.get(genUrl)
        res.raise_for_status()
        if raise_for_status == "200"
             goodWebsites.append(genURL)
```

This is where my imagination stops.  I need assistance completing this.  Not even sure I'm going about it the right way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try to send a [HEAD](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html#sec9.4) request first in order to check that the URL is valid, and only then download the package via a GET request.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2.7
listOfWebsites = [ website1, website2, website3, website4, and so on ]
goodWebsites = []
for eachWebsite in listOfWebsites:
    genURL = eachWebsite + "/" + packageName
    res = requests.head(genUrl)
    if res.ok:
         goodWebsites.append(genURL)
```